# Python simple naked objects

Tags: python, oop

What's the easiest way to create a naked object that I can assign attributes to?

The specific use case is: I'm doing various operations on a Django object instance, but sometimes the instance is None (there is on instance). In this case I'd like to create the simplest possible fake object such that I can assign values to its attributes (eg. `myobject.foo = 'bar'`).

Basically I'm looking for the Python equivalent of this piece of Javascript:

```
myobject = {}
myobject.foo = 'bar'
```

I know I can use a mock object/library for this, but I'm hoping for a very simple solution (as simple as the Javascript above). Is there a way to create a naked object instance? Something like:

```
myobject = object()
myobject.foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: That seems pretty naked to me. What exactly is the threshold that you want to stay below?

Comment: The python code above is pretty naked, but unfortunately it doesn't actually work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get for commenting too quickly. Of course :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to create a simple class first:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

myobject = Foo()
myobject.foo = 'bar'
```

You can make it a one-liner like this:

```
myobject = type("Foo", (object,), {})()
myobject.foo = 'bar'
```

The call to `type` functions identically to the previous `class` statement.

If you want to be *really* minimal...

```
myobject = type("", (), {})()
```

The key is that the built-in types (such as `list` and `object`) don't support user-defined attributes, so you need to create a type using either a `class` statement or a call to the 3-parameter version of `type`.

Comment: Nice, that is very minimal indeed. Unfortunately also quite unreadable, so I'll go with the first object method you recommend. If anyone has a minimal but readable version I'm still game...

Comment: Doesn't in fact have to inherit from object: `class Dummy(): pass` will do fine.

Comment: Probably. I shy away from old-style classes in Python 2 where possible.

Answer (score 34):

If you're using Python >= 3.3 you could always use **[SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)**; which is included in the Python `types` module.

**[SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)** is great because you also get a `repr` and equivalency testing for free; both of which might come in handy even for a minimalist object.

Translating the JavaScript in the OP’s question would look like:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

myobject = SimpleNamespace() # myobject = {}
myobject.foo = 'bar'
```

You can also use keyword arguments when instantiating **[SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)**.  These arguments will become attributes on the instantiated **[SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)**:

```
p = SimpleNamespace(name='gary')
p.age = 32
p # => namespace(age=32, name='gary')
```

So a quick and easy way to turn a dictionary into a  **[SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)** object  —provided the dictionary keys are proper identifiers—  is as simple as:

```
d = {
    'name': 'gary',
    'age': 33 # had a birthday. 
}
p = SimpleNamespace(**d)
```

Python >= 3.7 has **[dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html)** which are basically “**[mutable named tuples](https://youtu.be/T-TwcmT6Rcw)**”.   This could be something you may want to use if you have a lot of data objects.

Comment: SimpleNamespace along with providing key=values on initialization is by far the cleanest solution.

Comment: Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Bunch](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunch) module:

```
sudo pip install bunch
```

A bunch is a dictionary that allows to access its content via the `dict.key` syntax.

And then like that:

```
from bunch import Bunch
b = Bunch()
b.foo = "Bar"


b["foo2"] = "Bar2"
print b
>> Bunch(foo='Bar', foo2='Bar2')
b["foo"] = "Baz"
print b
>> Bunch(foo='Baz', foo2='Bar2')
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm coming here very late, but I'm surprised nobody has mentioned [`namedtuples`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which accomplish this kind of thing:

```
Foo = namedtuple('Foo', ['x'])
f = Foo(x='myattribute')
f.x
```

Comment: To use namedtuple, we should know the attributes in advance, which might not be the case here. You cannot add arbitrary attributes to the objects in this case.

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3,

```
class Obj: pass

o = Obj()
o.name = 'gary'
o.age = 32

o
# <__main__.Obj at 0x17235ca65c0>

o.__dict__
# {'name': 'gary', 'age': 32}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
class NakedObject(object):
    pass

myobject = NakedObject()
myobject.foo = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 4):

Functions can have attributes in Python 3. Compared to a naked class, you can save one whole line of code.

```
naked = lambda: None
naked.foo = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to subclass object first like this...

```
class Myobject(object):
    pass

myobject1 = Myobject()
myobject1.foo = 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
myobject={}
myobject['foo']='bar'
```

then it can be called like:

```
print myobject['foo']
```

or you could use a class object for this:

```
class holder(object):
    pass
```

then you can use something like this:

```
hold=holder()
hold.myobject='bar'
print hold.myobject
```

Comment: I'm looking specifically to use the dot notation for accessing the attributes so the same code that manipulates the django object instances can work on this - so I'd want myobject.foo instead of myobject['foo']

Comment: That's a dict in python, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use a dict, as per @PsychicOak's answer.

However, if you really want an object you can manipulate, try:

```
class FooClass(object): pass
```

You can then assign attributes on `FooClass` itself, or on instances, as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to create a [null object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) for my class:

```
class User(Model):
    username = CharField()
    password = CharField()


NONE_USER = User(username='', password='')
```

Then I use it where I would use your naked object.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases extending a `dict` can help you

like:

```
class SpecificModelData(dict):
   pass
   ...

class Payload(dict):
   ... enter code here
```

why a `dict`? it works nicely together with serializers.

Why new class? - it gives you a name and a new type