# How to make a variable collection in Python

Tags: python, variables, lua

I need to know how to do something like how in Lua you would use:

```
foo={
   x=7,
   y=5
}
```

and retrieve the variables with `foo.x`. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lua, but this looks like a dict. Have you considered that? The syntax would be `foo = {'x': 7, 'y': 5}; foo['x']`

Comment: I think this answer would help you: [How to use dot notation for dict in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16279578/6030424)

Comment: You're either looking to create a class or a dictionary with my lack of knowledge of Lua. Please explain more as to what this "collection" is to be used for and we can further help you.

Comment: You can use [**`types.SimpleNamespace`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49438171/1084416)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a dictionary, where you're able to access key , value pairs.

```
foo={
   'x':7,
   'y':5
}
```

the semicolon is used to assign the key to the value

```
foo = { 
 'key':value
}
```

Comment: OP wants to access values as attributes, not keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use a python Dictionary type:

```
foo = {
    'x' : 7,
    'y': 5
}
```

Retrieve with: `foo['x']`

Here's the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries